# Integral in Spherical and Rectangular Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

If I'm evaluating $\int^b_a r dz$, where $r$ is a variable in spherical coordinates and $z$ is a variable in rectangular coordinates, do I need to transform $dz$ in spherical coordinates? If so, how would I do that?

This question was spawned from integration of radiation fields for dipoles.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In spherical coordinates: (Assuming that "theta" is the angle made with the positive x-axis, and "phi" is the angle made with the positive z-axis)

z = r*cos(phi)

Also:

x = r*sin(phi)*cos(theta), and:

y = r*sin(phi)*sin(theta)

Comment: Thus, does "dz" (which indicates incremental changes in the z direction) become "dr" times cos(phi), where "dr" is the new differential?